# Execute python code with rendered variables in Tempita

Tags: python

I'm trying to run python code in Tempita using rendered variables:

```
{{py:
import subprocess
return subprocess.check_output(["do-something","--var=http://server_host:8000/"])
}}
```

However server_host is a variable. So if I do:

```
{{server_host}}
```

It gets rendered correctly. I'm trying to make use of the rendered output of {{server_host}} variable when running the python code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Tempita, but I think the following should work:

```
{{py:
import subprocess
return subprocess.check_output(["do-something","--var=http://"+server_host+":8000/"])
}}
```

Comment: Judging by the source code, this should work; the same namespace used for the `{{server_host}}` case is passed into the `exec` statement executing the python expression block.